# Changing postgres password in version 9.4

Tags: postgresql

I have PostgreSql 9.3 version installed in my ubuntu 14.04 machine. I just installed the 9.4 version as well and the port it is on is 5433(by default). When i give the command `psql --version`, it gives me the following:

```
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.4.1
```

So far so good! Now i am trying to change my password for my postgresql 9.4 and i gave the following command:

```
>>sudo -u postgres -p 5433 psql
psql (9.4.1, server 9.3.6)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# alter user postgres with password 'password';
ALTER ROLE
postgres=# \q
```

Now i tried connecting it on pgadmin3 but it would give me the password authentication failure. Am i doing it right?

Comment: Are the connection/authentication settings in your pg_hba.conf set up correctly? Try connecting with your local IP address in pgadmin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sudo -u postgres psql -p 5433`

Your `-p 5433` as you write it is treated as an option for `sudo`, not for `psql`. And you've connected to Postgres 9.3 on standard port.

Comment: but this command is asking for my postgres password which i have not setup yet

Answer (score 4):

Try using:

```
>>sudo -u postgres -p 5433 psql
psql (9.4.1, server 9.3.6)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \password
Enter new password:
Enter it again:
postgres=#
```

Comment: can you tell me the exact command? i am a newbie to linux and postgresql

Comment: The command is `\password`, a meta command of psql. Updated answer to include the original code.